# This is code is not removing a string from the firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase

This should delete the task from the database and I don't get any errors, it doesn't log further than `-1`. The HTML element gets deleted.

The code:

```
// Get the delete button
const deleteButton = taskElement.querySelector('.task-delete');

// Add click event listener to delete button
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("-1")
  // Create a popup to confirm the deletion
  createPopup("Delete Task?", "Are you sure you want to delete this task?", "", "confirm", function(confirm) {
    console.log("0")
    if (confirm) {
      console.log("1")
      // Delete the task from the database
      console.log("2")
      tasksRef.orderByChild('task').equalTo(taskText).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("3")
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          child.ref.delete();
          console.log("Deleted!")
        });
      });
      // Remove the task element from the page
      taskElement.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If it doesn't log `0`, then it likely doesn't execute it? Or are the logs hidden somewhere? If it's not executed, then it's a problem with the `createPopup` method/usage, rather than with firebase

Comment: I added logs to the `createPopup` function where everything was printed (`createPopup` code: https://pastebin.com/cnw1PhFN)

Comment: You can try to add a breakpoint at the `console.log("0")` line to see if it executes or not. If not, createPopup doesn't call the callback

Comment: Fixed It! It just changed the orginal code to this: `tasksRef.orderByChild('task').equalTo(taskText).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                  child.ref.set(null);
                });
              });`